# jQuery Timepicker dropdown displaying incorrectly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, timepicker

I've used this package without issue before. But now for the life of me, I'm having an issue with it displaying the dropdown correctly. I am using this along with the cocoon gem, to add new time fields as needed.

[image]

I have imported the scss into my `application.scss`. I have included the scripts in my `application.js` with `//= require timepicker/timepicker`, I have ensured that it is included *after* jQuery. Also, as you can see the field is populated with the time, just not formatted; which is also giving me problems as well.

```
<%= f.text_field :start_time, 
                 class: 'timepicker form-control col-sm-12', 
                 disabled: disabled %>
```

Thank you for any assistance that is able to be offered on this.

Also, here is the javascript that is in a script tag on the page.

```
  $('input.timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'H:i'
  });
```

**EDIT:**  For some reason my imports weren't working with my styling. I've got the dropdown looking as it should now. However, I am still unable to display the time in the text_field in a formatted manner in my edit form. It displays correctly when selecting a time, but when the edit page loads, it show the below format.

Comment: Have you tried starting every timepicker itself with an `#id`? So if you have 3 timepicker inputs you need 3 times  `$('input#timepicker1').timepicker({timeFormat: 'H:i'});`

Comment: @DennyMueller For some reason that alone did not fix it. I found a way to access the object in the form to set a value if one exists for display in show and when the edit page renders

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get it. I wasn't aware that I could access the object in the form with `f.object`. With that I was able to finally set the value with `value: f.object.start_time.strftime('%H:%M')`